# Compare signed integers and return either 0 or -1 in Thumb2 assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, micro-optimization, thumb

In thumb2 assembly, when r0 and r1 have **signed** integers, I like to have r1=-1 (i.e. 0xffffffff) if r0 < r1, otherwise r1=0.

I can simply code:

```
4288            cmp     r0, r1
bfb4            ite     lt
f04f 31ff       movlt.w r1, #-1
2100            movge   r1, #0
```

But I wonder if there is more optimized way either in cycles or in space.

If it were an **unsigned** comparison, I could use the carry flag:

```
4288            cmp     r0, r1
4189            sbcs    r1, r1
```

In ARM64, `cset r1, lt` would return 0 or 1, but I like to code in thumb2 assembly.

Comment: I think this is about as good as it gets.

Comment: Subtract and shift? `rsb r1, r0; asr r1, #31`

Comment: @Jester That's for **unsigned** comparison, I think.

Comment: @Jester: The sign bit of the result is only equal to the compare result if subtraction didn't overflow.  That's why x86 `jl` is `SF≠ OF` rather than just `SF`, for example.  But yes, if your inputs have limited range, so their absolute difference is never above INT_MAX, that's a useful optimization.

Answer (score 1):

**If your inputs have limited range so subtraction won't have signed overflow,** you can use Jester's suggestion of using the sign bit of a subtraction:

```
@@ With limited-range inputs
   rsb r1, r0          @ must not overflow, oVerflow flag must be 0 after this
   asr r1, #31         @ copy the sign bit of r0-r1 to all other bits
```

This works as long as `r0-r1` doesn't overflow a 2's complement signed integer.  Then the sign of the result will indeed be negative when `r0 < r1`.

Failing cases include `-10 < INT_MAX`, where the mathematical result is `-2147483657`, but truncated to 32-bit we get `0x7ffffff7` (`+2147483639`).  The V flag will be set, indicating signed o**v**erflow, and the N flag (sign bit) will be clear because the truncated result is not Negative, opposite of the sign of the mathematical non-truncated result.

That's why [signed compare conditions](https://community.arm.com/arm-community-blogs/b/architectures-and-processors-blog/posts/condition-codes-1-condition-flags-and-codes) like `lt` check `N != V` instead of just `N`, so for example `cmp` / `blt` works correctly with these inputs.

---

**If your code has to work correctly with arbitrary inputs (full-range), I don't think there's any room for improvement, not even in code-size.**  Using an `lt` condition, either branch or `it` predication, seems the only reasonable option.  Emulating 2's complement comparison manually is not going to be shorter than this.

Even outside an IT block, ARM Thumb2 doesn't have a 2-byte instruction for setting a register to `-1`.  (At least not that compilers know about or use.) `movs` doesn't sign-extend its immediate, and `mvn`/`mvns`-immediate is a 4-byte instruction.  So is `orrs r0, #-1`, not that you'd want that false dependency for performance anyway.  So even if we could produce the result in a different register than either input, there's no savings.

Current GCC and clang ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAbKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTHxdpgOaUIETMQEGT5%2BXLaY9nkM1bUEBWGR0XG2NXUNWc0KQ93BvcX9sQCUtqhexMjsHMEEANT8qBAbm0ykm/sRcyYA7FYaAIKbd5vEmATLDJsRJgDMbkybnwBimwAtFxNiBNhpPldrgB6aEPJ4vBTHV7EDSbBioLbEZqbBSoTYASVxAHcmAkEph0G9Pt9keNMEwqagqAcaRFNkRNiwmARkAgTDcLgARAXXUWwzbXABKAFlNqIGGAOFtuQRongxHgAF6YA5AkHEwgIPVmQERACearpBGIXkqAgAdKKTrUIGdLqL7ptYUwFCxNhBzGYWKgAG5I1FHcwfYFBs4fCzeuGSN6WzBIzChxibJYEFJYA6vAkAFTetFQyAA1p77o9nsRXrGEzW7hKAOpGoEAeQ%2BQJYBAQkT7tT5nyFtRYoYArFbASw8VQCICqOWeS2k5sAOJuNybLxKJFcsMRjRRswfEGQu4hYAno6o0XCjgLWicKe8PwcLSkVCcNzWaxcSWFZdWjHhSAITRnwWSsQA%2BD4HUkABOKcpyQswkMkAAOc4uHOFD4lfDhJA/KCf04XgFBAU9IK/Z9SDgWAYEQFBUBYBI6GichKDQdjOJiCdgC4MwzFPLBQzwVYADU8EwYkuwpT9wJoWg1WIKiIAiMiImCWpzU4cCdOYYhzS7CJtAqWjv14thBC7BhaH0ujSCwbkjHEZz8EeSosyo5zMFUCovDVAzeA2VoyNoPAImIPSPCwMibTwFhQoWFcmFvGS5IUxhQpkQQRDEdgpHy%2BQlDUMjdGaAwjBQADLH0aKqMgBZUASdo/MBLskTnAchznZAEi8Mc0DqALASYc5Yko1pLLSFwGHcTxGn8RaeiKEpsmSVIBBGJpEm29p1r6GIxlm%2B0OgmPa9HKC7OjqY6ZlOwYumusYJkezauAWPFllWCQXzfUjnN/DhJVlTZgGQZBNmEh0zADKKGC8VQ5gDXBCBIX5z2%2B3grOg0hYPgh08K4DRzg%2BXD8Ow84zH0TgSNIFKp1PT9v1ByjqIgqCFkYljeI4%2BgyAoCABf4kBBOE0SXMzSTMCy%2BTFLylS1I0rTnKMvS8s1kyzIshwyJsxgCHsxyyNcwxgA878vLm3yyICoKQu4MLBAi5yopiuKMDWb8kpSl20oMTLZMV3KXdKwrxBK/hBEUFR1Gc3QPn0S26ssaxGoiZq3R/dq0k6nth2If0BqGkaSDVVQJqmma2nmiBXDe0hAimDb%2BmaHIdvSZbRgO3I0k%2BjuWnrgR7vqXv9tu9px6H57xleyebo%2BtuToBxY/uKwGOHfUg2d4UHwblKGYbhhGICRlG0YgDGiGIbGLzmPGeYWBAGSwGJc6IxnmdZsiOdsFzfGcwYJwQQqTcmlM8KYRwnTIiHxgbswotzOivNmIQCQGLIW3FRZsUFv0CcoZziAmQDVYAgIbReAYJWGWElpKhxykpXgKtohq20rpEy2sOGmXMpZPKRs7IOScjbTAbkra%2B14LbHy6YHaBWQMFNY4FwpEW/J7WKJl4oSIgsQZKqU%2BDBwUArRhytZBR2KtIWOZUE6VRAHAtOpgM4NU9jnVq%2BcBCF17HOCcfZBrDQ%2BEKUaVcJpTgQSPOazhG6LWbq3Qoa9O6HTSM3LuR1V5PRuudGeV0l5nVHpdLoc9l6L0yFPFesS0nfQ3iBdeRFd773ImDQhxCfikMtgGSh1Dr63yxmBJ%2BKCtAgMJmAh08ERmjLGfTYiiCD7IKojRF%2BEyzC8BSmTP%2BINkHAIWFmdS81JBAA)) prefer unconditionally setting a register and then predicating one `mov`-immediate to overwrite it.  But that might just be a heuristic for Thumb mode that saves code-size if one of the constants allows a shorter instruction outside an IT block, or of predicating fewer instructions in case it fills up an IT block and needs another IT, or couldn't combine into one ITE.  That could happen in a larger function, or if other things are predicated on the same condition, but isn't a problem here.

In ARM mode (`-marm`), GCC prefers `cmp` ; `movge r0, #0` ; `mvnlt r0, #0` for all `-mcpu=` that I've looked at (cortex-a8, cortex-a53, cortex-a76 and unset).  (I'm looking at a function, so it returns in r0, but the inputs are r0 and r1 so it's still the same situation as yours.)

So that's exactly the same as your strategy for Thumb mode.  Unless an instruction inside an IT block is slower than being outside, probably best to do what you're doing.

```
@ GCC -O3, probably no better than yours, but same size
foo:
 cmp    r1, r0
 mov.w  r0, #4294967295 ; 0xffffffff        @ 4-byte instruction
 it ge
 movge  r0, #0                              @ 2-byte instruction
@ r0 and r1 are swapped vs. your version since functions return in r0
```